# Assistance on arabic text on TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, languages, rotating, paths

I attempting to use both arabic and TikZ pictures but, I have four problems:

1. The Arabic words appear in reverse order, the first word appears finally ...
2. The sentence is not in arc as in the English sentence.
3. The numbers appears Idiens digits and not in Arabic.
4. Most of the ornaments do not appear or appear in different places.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfornament,tikzrput}         % altermundus.com/pages/tkz/tikzrput/
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}  % altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/
```

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=machriq]{arabic}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5
,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Scheherazade}
\begin{document}

\begin{Arabic}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[ultra thick,color=blue] circle[radius=6cm] circle[radius=7cm]  ;
\draw[line width=2mm,color=blue] circle[radius=7.4cm]  ;
\draw[line width=0.5mm,color=blue] circle[radius=5cm]  ;

\path 
    [rotate=170,postaction={decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={|}{|},text={|\huge| Knowledge Raising House has no Mainstay {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt,color=blue]{15}} And Ignorance Destroys House of Glory and Honor {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt,symmetry=v,color=blue]{15}}},
      text align=fit to path,reverse path}, decorate}]
     circle[radius=6.2cm] ; 
      \rput{-20}(1.5,4.2){\pgfornament[scale=.2,color=blue]{87}}
      \rput{20}(-1.5,4.2){\pgfornament[scale=.2,color=blue]{87}}
      \rput{-20}(-1.5,-4.2){\pgfornament[scale=.2,color=blue]{87}}
      \rput{20}(1.5,-4.2){\pgfornament[scale=.2,color=blue]{87}} 
      \rput{}(-2.5,-2.75){\pgfornament[scale=.25,color=blue]{10}} 
      \rput{}(2.5,-2.75){\pgfornament[scale=.25,color=blue]{10}} 
      \rput{}(0,4){\pgfornament[scale=.2,color=blue]{66}}
      \rput{}(0,2){\pgfornament[scale=.3,color=blue]{70}} 
      \rput{}(0,-3){\pgfornament[scale=.3,color=blue]{70}} 
      \rput(0,0){\pgfornament[scale=.6,color=blue]{75}}
      \rput{-90}(2,0){\pgfornament[scale=.6,color=blue]{72}}
      \rput{90}(-2,0){\pgfornament[scale=.6,symmetry=v,color=blue]{72}}  
 \node[font=\huge,color=blue] at (0,3){} ;

\path 
    [rotate=218,postaction={decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={|}{|}, text={|\Huge| \AR{والجهل يهدم بيت العز والشرف} {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt,color=blue]{15}} 14-12-1968 {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt,symmetry=v,color=blue]{15}} \AR{العِلْمُ يرفع بيتًا لا عماد له} {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt,color=blue]{15}}},
      text align=fit to path,reverse path}, decorate}]
     circle[radius=5.2cm] ;  
  \node[font=\huge,color=blue] at (0,-2){} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{Arabic}

\end{document}

Answer (score 5):

Just put the *individual* words in curly brackets, as follows:

{لها} {عماد} {لا} {بيوتا} {يبني} {العلم}

with:

```
\usepackage [utf] {arabxetex}
```

[image: Arabic text with Tikz and ArabXeTeX]

Answer (score 2):

You've not really provided a *minimal* working example, but I will try to answer points (2) and (4) as best I can, as I am not that familiar with how "right-to-left" languages work with `latex`. I am using TeX Live 2012.

It's not clear whether you are compiling with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Only a recent version of `polyglossia` is compatible with `lualatex` (not sure if it is on CTAN yet), so I presume you are compiling with `xelatex`.

When compiling your file with `xelatex` I get a whole load of `Undefined control sequence \rput`. This is why some of the ornaments are in the wrong place. This seems to be because`tikzrput` only defines `\rput` according to `\ifpdf`, but `xelatex` defines `\ifxetex`. You can get around this by putting

```
\let\ifpdf=\ifxetex
```

just before you load the `tikzrput` package.

The command `\AR` does not appear to be defined. Either way, the text is consumed token by token so \AR is consumed on it's own. Also, the Arabic text following `\AR` is between braces, so is treated as a single unit and not typeset around the curve. The Arabic text is typeset around the curve if I remove the `\AR` and the surrounding braces.

The rest I am not sure on.